# Spring @cacheable not working when used in util/library external jar for the spring boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache

I have a jar file which contains common code across multiple application.
I have a service in there which is annotated with **@cacheable** annotation.
but it is not caching the values.

**Note** : No ehcache.xml or cache managers are defined in the common jar file

ehcache.xml is defined in the main Spring boot application in the following fashion

> ```
> <cache name="mainApplicationCache"
>        timeToLiveSeconds="3600">
> </cache>
>
> <cache name="commonJarCache"
>        timeToLiveSeconds="3600">
> </cache>
> ```

Main Application Code goes likes the following

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"**commonJar Packages**","**Main Application Packages**"})
public class MainSpringBootApplication{...
```

CacheManager configuration class goes like the following

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {
    private net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager;

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Closing Cache Manager");
        cacheManager.shutdown();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        log.debug("Starting Ehcache");
        cacheManager = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();        
        EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        ehCacheManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
        return ehCacheManager;
    }
}
```

**Note** : mainApplicationCache is refrenced in a service in the main application code package works fine and caches the result.

commonJarCache is refrenced in the common jar code package is not working?.

Both the service interface and implementations are in the library jar

The Generic service interface is defined as like below

```
@Service
public interface CachedService<E ,T ,R>{

    public R cachedMethod(String goal);

    public SomeObject<E,T,R> nonCachedMethod(String goal);

}
```

and the service implementation is like below

```
       @Service
        public class CachedServiceImpl
                implements CachedService<ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC> {

            @Override   
            @Cacheable(cacheNames = "commonJarCache")
            public ObjectC cachedMethod(String goal) {

            }

            public SomeObject<ObjectA,ObjectB,ObjectC> nonCachedMethod(String goal){
              ObjectC c = cachedMethod(goal);
}
        }

    public interface MainService<Y,X ,E ,T,R > {
        public void entryFromAppJar(List<X> input,String goal);
    }

    @Service
    public class MainServiceImpl<T>
            implements MainService<T, ObjectD, ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC> {

        @Autowired
        private CachedService<ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC> cachedService;

        @Override   
        public void entryFromAppJar(List<ObjectD> inputs, String goal) {
            cachedService.nonCachedMethod(goal);
            //Implementation goes here
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your pointers to come over this issue.

Comment: Are you creating the beans of the class that you are using in CommonJar code. How are those objects created. Are they managed by Spring container.???

Comment: @praneeth yes they are managed by spring container... All the beans in the common jar code are created using spring annotations.

Comment: unrelated but you can remove your whole CacheConfiguration, Spring Boot does that for you already. Perhaps you could show the service that doesn't work? Or share a sample?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll i have updated the service example in the question.The service interface is a Generic interface will it create any issue ?..

Comment: @StephaneNicoll i have updated the example...change the mode to Aspectj in the enablecaching annotation but no luck.pls provide your suggestions

Comment: update : cacheable annotation works on nonCachedMethod perfectly without any changes.But it is not working over cachedMethod even with enablecaching annotation in adviceMode aspectj.